# Is my way using coroutine in Unity wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Im using coroutine to make a little break that's reloading the bullet. I don’t know why this doesn’t work, which is to say, there is no time waiting. I’m probably not using the coroutine correctly. Can somebody help me?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Time.time > nextFire && !inventoryInterface.activeSelf)
{
    //aimAnimator.SetTrigger("Shoot");
    nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
    if (count < gun.bulletsInAMagazine)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = UtilsClass.GetMouseWorldPosition();
        OnShoot?.Invoke(this, new OnShootEventArgs
        {
            gunEndPointPosition = aimGunEndPointPosition.position,
            shootPosition = mousePosition
        });
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
        StartCoroutine(FireCooldown());
        Debug.Log("Reloading");
    }
    //StartCoroutine(FireCooldown());
    //allowFire = true;
}
```

And the enumerator:

```cs
IEnumerator FireCooldown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gun.reloadTime);
}
```

Comment: Set your variable in the coroutine, after the delay.  StartCoroutine does NOT create a delay, the delay is contained within the coroutine method.

Comment: in short: yes this is wrong ... in general: If it doesn't do what you expected it to do then it is probably wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `allowFire` bool to true inside the couroutine

```
IEnumerator FireCooldown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gun.reloadTime);
    allowFire = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a coroutine , the function you want to run should write under the yield return.

```
IEnumerator FireCooldown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gun.reloadTime);//check that gun.reloadTime is not null                         
                                                                    
     // and type here the method that you want to run after reloading
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide some description to the provided code